# Determine whether UIView is visible to the user?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, visibility, nstimer

Is it possible to determine whether my `UIView` is visible to the user or not?

My View is added as a `subview` several times into a `UITabBarController`.

Each instance of this view has an `NSTimer` that updates the view.

However, I don't want to update a view which is not visible to the user.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you can, would you consider updating your selected answer to the one with the most upvotes—that is, the one that checks `.window`  (by walkingbrad), as the answer that checks `.superview` (by mahboudz) is not technically correct and has caused bugs for me.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can check if:

- it is hidden, by checking view.hidden
- it is in the view hierarchy, by checking `view.superview != nil`
- you can check the bounds of a view to see if it is on screen

The only other thing I can think of is if your view is buried behind others and can't be seen for that reason.  You may have to go through all the views that come after to see if they obscure your view.

Comment: I did that this way but forgot to post the solution here :) Thanks (+1)

Comment: How did you accomplish your obscurity check?

Comment: Not easily.  Check the bounds of all opaque child views, and keep track of portions of your view that aren't obscured to check against the next child subview.  To make it easier, you might want to define a few points and if those points are visible, then assume your view is.  You can choose whether all points being visible is an indication that your view is visible, or whether any single point visible will satisfy your requirement.

Comment: the third one works even if UIView is inside another UIView which is inside a scroll view?

Comment: What will still fall through is if one of the superviews is hidden.

Comment: I would add to the list checking an alpha

Comment: It seems, unfortunately, this is not a comprehensive answer. There are many possible reasons a view might be visible, or not, making it not easily possible to determine.

Answer (score 135):

**For anyone else that ends up here:**

To determine if a UIView is onscreen somewhere, rather than checking `superview != nil`, it is better to check if `window != nil`. In the former case, it is possible that the view has a superview but that the superview is not on screen:

```
if (view.window != nil) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Of course you should also check if it is `hidden` or if it has an `alpha > 0`.

Regarding not wanting your `NSTimer` running while the view is not visible, you should hide these views manually if possible and have the timer stop when the view is hidden. However, I'm not at all sure of what you're doing.

Comment: ay caramba! just what I needed to kill the cycled animations

Comment: Sorry I voted this up, it doesnt work.  When I do `po [self.view recursiveDescription]` my subviews are shown in the view hierarchy, yet their `view.window` is always nil.

Comment: @LogicsaurusRex You can have a view hierarchy that is not currently being shown in the window (hence why I originally re-answered the question). In the case you've outlined here, I imagine that `self.view` also has a `window` of nil. Is that the case? (sorry for late reply)

Comment: I would buy you a bottle of wine;)

Answer (score 41):

This will determine if a view's frame is within the bounds of all of its superviews (up to the root view). One practical use case is determining if a child view is (at least partially) visible within a scrollview.

#### Swift 5.x:

```
func isVisible(view: UIView) -> Bool {
    func isVisible(view: UIView, inView: UIView?) -> Bool {
        guard let inView = inView else { return true }
        let viewFrame = inView.convert(view.bounds, from: view)
        if viewFrame.intersects(inView.bounds) {
            return isVisible(view: view, inView: inView.superview)
        }
        return false
    }
    return isVisible(view: view, inView: view.superview)
}
```

#### Older swift versions

```
func isVisible(view: UIView) -> Bool {
    func isVisible(view: UIView, inView: UIView?) -> Bool {
        guard let inView = inView else { return true }
        let viewFrame = inView.convertRect(view.bounds, fromView: view)
        if CGRectIntersectsRect(viewFrame, inView.bounds) {
            return isVisible(view, inView: inView.superview)
        }
        return false
    }
    return isVisible(view, inView: view.superview)
}
```

Potential improvements:

- Respect `alpha` and `hidden`.
- Respect `clipsToBounds`, as a view may exceed the bounds of its superview if false.

Comment: Perfect. I have a stack view as the content of a scroll view and determining which of the  arrangedSubviews are (at least partially) visible is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for posting this @johngibb. My use case was needing to check if it was completely visible and I found I could achieve this be replacing `intersects` with `contains(_:)`

Answer (score 21):

The solution that worked for me was to first check if the view has a window, then to iterate over superviews and check if:

1. the view is not hidden.
2. the view is within its superviews bounds.

Seems to work well so far.

### Swift 3.0

```
public func isVisible(view: UIView) -> Bool {

  if view.window == nil {
    return false
  }

  var currentView: UIView = view
  while let superview = currentView.superview {

    if (superview.bounds).intersects(currentView.frame) == false {
      return false;
    }

    if currentView.isHidden {
      return false
    }

    currentView = superview
  }

  return true
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer. This can fail in UITableView and UIScrollView from what I can tell though.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me inside `UITableView` and `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 8):

I benchmarked both @Audrey M. and @John Gibb their solutions.
And @Audrey M. his way performed better (times 10).
So I used that one to make it observable.

I made a RxSwift Observable, to get notified when the UIView became visible.
This could be useful if you want to trigger a banner 'view' event

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import RxSwift

extension UIView {
    var isVisibleToUser: Bool {

        if isHidden || alpha == 0 || superview == nil {
            return false
        }

        guard let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController else {
            return false
        }

        let viewFrame = convert(bounds, to: rootViewController.view)

        let topSafeArea: CGFloat
        let bottomSafeArea: CGFloat

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            topSafeArea = rootViewController.view.safeAreaInsets.top
            bottomSafeArea = rootViewController.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        } else {
            topSafeArea = rootViewController.topLayoutGuide.length
            bottomSafeArea = rootViewController.bottomLayoutGuide.length
        }

        return viewFrame.minX >= 0 &&
            viewFrame.maxX <= rootViewController.view.bounds.width &&
            viewFrame.minY >= topSafeArea &&
            viewFrame.maxY <= rootViewController.view.bounds.height - bottomSafeArea

    }
}

extension Reactive where Base: UIView {
    var isVisibleToUser: Observable<Bool> {
        // Every second this will check `isVisibleToUser`
        return Observable<Int>.interval(.milliseconds(1000),
                                        scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .map { [base] _ in
            return base.isVisibleToUser
        }.distinctUntilChanged()
    }
}
```

Use it as like this:

```swift
import RxSwift
import UIKit
import Foundation

private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

private func _checkBannerVisibility() {

    bannerView.rx.isVisibleToUser
        .filter { $0 }
        .take(1) // Only trigger it once
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
            // ... Do something
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Comment: @Audrey M answer only checks to see if it's within the screen bounds and not if it's actually visible. John Gibb's answer is the one that actually checks if a view can be seen.

Answer (score 5):

Tested solution.

```
func isVisible(_ view: UIView) -> Bool {
    if view.isHidden || view.superview == nil {
        return false
    }

    if let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController,
        let rootView = rootViewController.view {

        let viewFrame = view.convert(view.bounds, to: rootView)

        let topSafeArea: CGFloat
        let bottomSafeArea: CGFloat

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            topSafeArea = rootView.safeAreaInsets.top
            bottomSafeArea = rootView.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        } else {
            topSafeArea = rootViewController.topLayoutGuide.length
            bottomSafeArea = rootViewController.bottomLayoutGuide.length
        }

        return viewFrame.minX >= 0 &&
               viewFrame.maxX <= rootView.bounds.width &&
               viewFrame.minY >= topSafeArea &&
               viewFrame.maxY <= rootView.bounds.height - bottomSafeArea
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I you truly want to know if a view is visible to the user you would have to take into account the following:

- Is the view's window not nil and equal to the top most window
- Is the view, and all of its superviews alpha >= 0.01 (threshold value also used by UIKit to determine whether it should handle touches) and not hidden
- Is the z-index (stacking value) of the view higher than other views in the same hierarchy.
- Even if the z-index is lower, it can be visible if other views on top have a transparent background color, alpha 0 or are hidden.

Especially the transparent background color of views in front may pose a problem to check programmatically. The only way to be truly sure is to make a programmatic snapshot of the view to check and diff it within its frame with the snapshot of the entire screen. This won't work however for views that are not distinctive enough (e.g. fully white).

For inspiration see the method isViewVisible in the  [iOS Calabash-server project](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios-server/blob/develop/calabash/Classes/Utils/LPTouchUtils.m)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest Swift 5 solution I could come up with that worked in my situation (I was looking for a button embedded in my tableViewFooter).

John Gibbs solution also worked but in my cause I did not need all the recursion.

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let viewFrame = scrollView.convert(targetView.bounds, from: targetView)
        if viewFrame.intersects(scrollView.bounds) {
            // targetView is visible 
        }
        else {
            // targetView is not visible
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In viewWillAppear set a value "isVisible" to true, in viewWillDisappear set it to false.  Best way to know for a UITabBarController subviews, also works for navigation controllers.

Comment: yeah, it seems to be the only reliable way

Answer (score 2):

Another useful method is `didMoveToWindow()`
Example: When you push view controller, views of your previous view controller will call this method. Checking `self.window != nil` inside of `didMoveToWindow()` helps to know whether your view is appearing or disappearing from the screen.

Answer (score 1):

This can help you figure out if your UIView is the top-most view. Can be helpful:

```
let visibleBool = view.superview?.subviews.last?.isEqual(view)
//have to check first whether it's nil (bc it's an optional) 
//as well as the true/false 
if let visibleBool = visibleBool where visibleBool { value
  //can be seen on top
} else {
  //maybe can be seen but not the topmost view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
func isDisplayedInScreen() -> Bool
{
 if (self == nil) {
     return false
  }
    let screenRect = UIScreen.main.bounds 
    // 
    let rect = self.convert(self.frame, from: nil)
    if (rect.isEmpty || rect.isNull) {
        return false
    }
    // 若view 隐藏
    if (self.isHidden) {
        return false
    }

    // 
    if (self.superview == nil) {
        return false
    }
    // 
    if (rect.size.equalTo(CGSize.zero)) {
        return  false
    }
    //
    let intersectionRect = rect.intersection(screenRect)
    if (intersectionRect.isEmpty || intersectionRect.isNull) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score -4):

In case you are using hidden property of view then :

view.hidden (objective C) or view.isHidden(swift) is read/write property. So you can easily read or write

**For swift 3.0**

```
if(view.isHidden){
   print("Hidden")
}else{
   print("visible")
}
```