# Is the UIView visible?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to determine if a UIView is visible accounting all transforms/hidden/alpha in all 'super' layers including what iOS can bring on top my application as well?

I'm not referring to what has already been discussed where *isVisible* (And the other examples) is actually returning true even when other UIViews are stacked on top.

[Determine if UIView is visible to the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536923/determine-if-uiview-is-visible-to-the-user)

Let's say I create a UIView CGRect(0,0,100,100) and attach to my view. Then I pull down the notifications from the system on top of my UIView. Can I then know somehow I'm covered?

Thanks for helping,

/Anders.

Comment: you can try UnitTests or UITests for achieving this

Comment: Note that iOS (as many other OS-es) uses buffering, which means that if your view is not marked as dirty then it might not be asked to redraw itself. Thus your question should be targeted against the visibility of your view.

Comment: True. Ill change to visible.

Comment: Notification bar will pause your app. It is basically overlapping your app, therefore testing inside the app wont help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can test it in UITest by calling ‘uiView.isHittable’