# How to detect if the SwiftUI view was displayed to the user?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

There is a pretty classic scenario when the view was shown and you send view shown event to some analytics platform.

How do I detect if the first view appeared after the second one was closed?

```
var body: some View {
    Button("Show second") {
        isSecondViewShown.toggle()
    }
    .onAppear {
        print("First appeared")
    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isSecondViewShown) {
        Button("Close second") {
            isSecondViewShown.toggle()
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("Second appeared")
        }
    }
}
```

`onAppear`(which feels natural) does not work in this case. When you tap "Show Second" button and then "Close Second" button the following will be printed in logs:

```
First appeared
Second appeared
```

Instead of:

```
First appeared
Second appeared
First appeared
```

You can of course observe `isSecondViewShown` but it's not reliable and misleading.

Comment: Might help: [How to check if a view is displayed on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73038067/4667835)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a view is displayed on the screen? (Swift 5 and SwiftUI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595900/how-to-check-if-a-view-is-displayed-on-the-screen-swift-5-and-swiftui)

Comment: @MrDeveloper No, these are also workarounds and not all of them apply to `fullScreenCover`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to be more specific on your conditions, because as stated, while it's hard to know when the first view is shown, it's easy to know when the second view is closed (and the first view is then shown *again*). So the very simple thing to do is to watch when `isSecondViewShown` flips from `true` to `false`, meaning it's no longer shown:

```
    @State var isSecondViewShown: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if oldValue && !isSecondViewShown { // <-- watch for change from true to false
                print("We are back to first view after showing the second view!")
            }
        }
    }
  
    var body: some View { // ... same as before
```

Another option is a bit more involved: force `onAppear` on the view by having it in a container that has to redraw as a result of second view disappearance. This is by using an `.id` modifier:

```
    @State var isSecondViewShown: Bool = false
    @State var firstViewId: Int = 0 // <-- update it every time second view closes
  
    var body: some View {
        firstView
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isSecondViewShown) {
            Button("Close second") {
                isSecondViewShown.toggle()
                firstViewId += 1 // <-- update the id to force redraw of the parent container of the view
            }
            .onAppear {
                print("Second appeared")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var firstView: some View {
        ZStack { // <-- paren of the view we want the `onAppear` to be called
            Button("Show second \(firstViewId)") { // <-- this view will call `onAppear` every time its parent was redrawn
                isSecondViewShown.toggle()
            }
            .onAppear { // <-- this is what you want to happen every time second view disappears
                print("First appeared")
            }
        }
        .id(firstViewId) // <-- this id will cause parent container to redraw
    }
```

So the above will cause:

```
Second appeared
First appeared
Second appeared
First appeared
```

As you can see I didn't solve your actual issue: how to find out that the view is *displayed* (both solutions rely on second view *disappearance* instead). So these are workarounds really

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.fullScreenCover(isPresented:)` you can use `.fullScreenCover(item:)` by changing `isSecondViewShown` to an optional, you can use that. Here is the code I used:

```
struct FirstScreen: View {
    @State private var selectedView: SecondScreen?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Button("Go to second screen") {
                selectedView = SecondScreen()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedView){ _ in
            if selectedView == nil{
                print("On first view.")
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(item: $selectedView) { screen in
            NavigationStack {
                HStack {
                    screen
                }
                .toolbar {
                    HStack{
                        Button("Back") {
                            selectedView = nil
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `SecondScreen` struct:

```
struct SecondScreen: View, Identifiable, Equatable{
    var id = UUID()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Second Screen")
            .onAppear{
                print("On second screen")
            }
    }
}
```

And this usage can be modified and used in other ways like putting it in a array to make multi-pages.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest very simple and straightforward solution that may solve the task.
Instead of trying to catch if the moment when underlying ("First") view appears onscreen we can easily detect when presented ("Second") view is dismissed. Yes, in general this is not the same event, but in many cases – it is. In these cases you can achieve the desired result as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isSecondViewShown = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show second") {
            isSecondViewShown.toggle()
        }
        .onAppear {
            appeared()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isSecondViewShown, onDismiss: appeared) {
            Button("Close second") {
                isSecondViewShown.toggle()
            }
            .onAppear {
                print("Second appeared")
            }
        }
    }
    private func appeared() {
        print("First appeared")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`onAppear` refers to the underlying `UIView`. Since you are using `fullScreenCover` the `UIButton` wasn't removed, thus never disappeared, so the output is correct.

Answer (score -1):

The reason that the `First appeared` is not being printed the second time is because the `.fullScreenCover` acts like a sheet. Therefore, the first view has not actually disappeared yet.

The first solution is through the use of `onDisappear` on the `.fullScreenCover` button. However, this means it's not checking whether the first view is coming into view, but if the second one has fully left the view. Like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isSecondViewShown: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show second") {
            isSecondViewShown.toggle()
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("First appeared")
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isSecondViewShown) {
            Button("Close second") {
                isSecondViewShown.toggle()
            }
            .onAppear {
                print("Second appeared")
            }
            .onDisappear {
                print("First appeared")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second solution is a bit more work but allows you to have multiple pages working on the same view. But... there is no `.fullScreenCover` animation. This can be done like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var currentView: ViewTypes = .firstView

    var body: some View {
        if currentView == .firstView {
            Button("Show second") {
                currentView = .secondView
            }
            .onAppear {
                print("First appeared")
            }
        }
    
        else if currentView == .secondView {
            Button("Close second") {
                currentView = .firstView
            }
            .onAppear {
                print("Second appeared")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `ViewTypes` is:

```
enum ViewTypes {
    case firstView
    case secondView
}
```

Through the use of `withAnimation` however, you can achieve custom animations to fit your needs. Hope this helps!