# How to move Text to NavigationTitle when scrolling past it

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

A lot of apps (for example the Apple Music app) move some text only to the NavigationTitle once a user scrolls past it.
Is there a way to do this in SwiftUI (preferably without using GeometryReader or ScrollviewReader)?

Here’s what I’m looking for:
[image: example in the Apple Music app]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the simplest way to achieve this is to use `onAppear` and `onDisappear` for the content you want to be a title. I.e. something like this:

```
struct SomeView: View {

    @State var songTitle = "Whenever You Need Somebody" // Probably comes form some data model
    @State var screenTitle = "" // <-- what to show in screen title, nothing by default

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView { // Just taking this combo as example, could be a list, or a form, or anything else with scroll
            LazyVStack {
                // ... some elements
                Text(songTitle)
                    .onAppear {
                        screenTitle = "" // <-- hides title when this text is visible
                    } 
                    .onDisappear {
                        screenTitle = songTitle // <-- shows title when this text is not visible
                    }
                // ... some elements
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This basic solution will work well on some layouts, but may require some fine tuning on others. This is because SwiftUI's `onAppear` and `onDisappear` are not at exactly the moment when view is shown or hidden, it's rather done a few lines ahead of time (for `onAppear`), and a few lines after for `onDisappear`. So in some layouts you may need to have these events for some elements that come before and after the text you want to use for a title. Or you may implement a more sophisticated solution using `GeometryReader` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73038067/5318223))

Comment: This works pretty well, especially when applied to a view above the text.